# Get docx element from doc.element.iter()

Tags: python-3.x, element, paragraph, python-docx

**QUESTION: How do I use the `child` object (below) to actually get the paragraph or table object?**

This is based on the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130957/how-to-iterate-over-everything-in-a-python-docx-document), which referenced docx [Issue 40](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/40).

Unfortunately, none of the code posted there appears to work with commit [e784a73](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx)   but I was able to get close by an examination of the code (and trial and error)

I have the following ...

```
def iter_block_items(parent):
    """
    Yield each paragraph and table child within *parent*, in document order.
    Each returned value is an instance of either Table or Paragraph.
    """
    print(type(parent))
    if isinstance(parent, docx.document.Document):
        parent_elm = doc.element.body
    elif isinstance(parent, _Cell):
        parent_elm = parent._tc
    else:
        raise ValueError("something's not right")

    for child in parent_elm.iter():
        if isinstance(child, docx.oxml.text.paragraph.CT_P):
            yield ("(paragraph)", child)
        elif isinstance(child, docx.oxml.table.CT_Tbl):
            yield ("(table)", child)

for i in iter_block_items(doc): 
    print(i)
```

This successfully iterates through the elements, and gives me the following output ...

```
doc= <class 'docx.document.Document'>
<class 'docx.document.Document'>
('(table)', <CT_Tbl '<w:tbl>' at 0x10c9ce0e8>)
('(paragraph)', <CT_P '<w:p>' at 0x10c9ceef8>)
('(paragraph)', <CT_P '<w:p>' at 0x10c9ce0e8>)
('(paragraph)', <CT_P '<w:p>' at 0x10c9cef98>)
('(paragraph)', <CT_P '<w:p>' at 0x10c9ce0e8>)
('(table)', <CT_Tbl '<w:tbl>' at 0x10c9ceef8>)
('(paragraph)', <CT_P '<w:p>' at 0x10c9cef48>)
('(paragraph)', <CT_P '<w:p>' at 0x10c9cef48>)
('(paragraph)', <CT_P '<w:p>' at 0x10c9cef98>)
```

**All I need at this point is: the text from each paragraph, and the table object for the table - so I can iterate through its cells.**

But `child.text` (for a paragraph) does not return the paragraph text (as it would in the example below) because the `child` object does not actually the paragraph object, but an element object that should be able to 'get' it.

```
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    print(para.text)
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried:

```
yield child.text
(yields "None")
```

and

```
from docx.text import paragraph
yield paragraph(child)
(Errors with TypeError: 'module' object is not callable)
```

and

```
from docx.oxml.text import paragraph
yield paragraph(child)
(Errors with TypeError: 'module' object is not callable)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate proxy objects for each element if you want the API properties and methods. That's where those live.

```
if isinstance(child, CT_P):
    yield Paragraph(child, parent)
elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):
    yield Table(child, parent)
```

This will generate `Paragraph` and `Table` objects. A `Paragraph` object has a `.text` property. For a table you'll need to dig down to cells.

What you were getting with your code is the underlying XML element objects, which use a low-level `lxml` interface (actually elaborated a bit with the so-called `oxml` and/or `xmlchemy` interface) which is lower level than you probably want unless you're extending the behaviors of a proxy object like `Paragraph`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I'll try it. I notice the 'Paragraph' is capitalized, which means I'm not importing the right classes. (I'm importing `from docx.oxml.text import paragraph` or `from docx.text import paragraph`). Can you tell me the right `Paragraph` class to import?

Comment: Ah. I found it: `from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph`